# ¿Como eliminar imágenes almacenadas en media usando DeleteView en DJango?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-class-based-views

Tengo el siguiente modelo **Cliente**:

```
def custom_upload_to(instance, filename):
    try:
        old_instance = Cliente.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        old_instance.photo.delete()
        return 'clientes/' + filename
    except:
        return 'clientes/' + filename


TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS = (
    (0, 'Tarjeta de indentidad'),
    (1, 'Cédula'),
    (2, 'Pasaporte'),
    (3, 'Cédula extranjería'),
)


class Cliente(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nombre", max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Apellidos", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    document_type = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Tipo de documento", choices=TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS, default=1)
    document = models.CharField(verbose_name="Número de documento", max_length=200, unique=True)
    cell_phone = models.CharField(verbose_name="Celular", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name="Telefono", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fecha de nacimiento", null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Correo electronico", null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    direction = models.CharField(verbose_name="Dirección", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha de edición")

    def __str__(self):
        return ('{} {}'.format(self.name, self.last_name))

    def get_tipo_documento(self):
        tipo = TIPOS_DOCUMENTOS[self.document_type][1]
        return tipo

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cliente'
```

Y tengo esta view para el modelo

```
class ClienteDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, SuperuserRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Cliente
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cliente:list')
    template_name = 'cliente/cliente_confirm_delete.html'
```

Este es mi proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y resulta que cuando elimino un cliente no se me esta eliminado la imagen del mismo, ¿qué puedo hacer para que cuando se elimine el cliente al mismo tiempo se elimine la imagen?

He pensado en sobre escribir algun metodo como el `def get` o algo asi pero no se como hacerlo,

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo logre solucionar siguiendo estos pasos usando `django-cleanup`

primero  lo instale

`pip install django-cleanup`

y despues instale la app y listo

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
    'django_cleanup', # should go after your apps
)
```

*Link de la respuesta donde encontré esta solución*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28986357/7151942